# How to give time delay for PhonenumberUtils.PAUSE() in android?

Tags: java, android, phone-number

I am creating a conference manager application .I am Using the PhonenumberUtils.PAUSE() for time delay during the call.It is only working for few seconds.I want to make it pause for more seconds according to my wish.How can i do that can anyone help me?

```
String telUri = "tel:" + 121 + PhoneNumberUtils.PAUSE +  4 
        +  PhoneNumberUtils.PAUSE + 6 ;
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse(telUri));
startActivity(callIntent);
```

Now the call is going to 121 and without any time delay it is executing the number 4 and same as 6 .I want to give time delay for 121 and 4 .How can i give?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the PhoneNumberUtils.PAUSE will wait for 2 seconds ,and the value for PhoneNumberUtils.PAUSe is ",".

ProfileDo profile = adapter.getProfile(profileid);

```
    String call = "tel:";

    for (StepDO step : profile.getSteps()) {
```

//Encoding the value if it contains any symbol like #

```
        String value = URLEncoder.encode(step.getValue());

        int delay = step.getDelay();
        String pausesStr = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < delay/2; i++) {
            pausesStr += PhoneNumberUtils.PAUSE;
        }
        call += value + pausesStr;

        System.out.println(""+call);
    }
    Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse(call));
    startActivity(callIntent);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

That's a dialer thing, the time it takes for one pause is not really under your control but is *usually* 2-3 seconds. If you want a longer pause - just use two pauses in succession.

Also, use `StringBuilder` (memory reasons)

```
String doublePause = PhoneNumberUtils.PAUSE + PhoneNumberUtils.PAUSE;
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("tel:").append(121).append(doublePause).append(4).append(doublePause).append(6);
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse(sb.toString()));
```

Comment: Thanks.In my case I am getting the delay time  from the user how can I  set the user delay time

Comment: I'm not sure what user delay time is

Comment: You mean, you want to allow user to set the exact delay value? Can't do that, but you can let user select it with 3-sec delta. Like, field, + and - buttons. User hits + and the field increases from 3 sec to 6 sec --- and internally you just use 2 pauses instead of one. Or, you can just use a combo box instead of all that. Just give user 3-4 options (e.g. {3, 6, 9, 12}) --- they are very unlikely to ever need more than that.

Comment: ya correct but whatever value the user is giving as the delay should act according to the users delay ...If you have free time check this link  https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.naresh.confmgr&hl=en

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I'm talking about. You can see on screenshots, that the delay is always an even number: 2, 4, 8. You need to use something other than a `TextField` to restrict user input to the values you want. Just leave them no options to input delays that you can't use, make them choose from the list of possible delays you define. It's even more convenient - no need to type the numbers on the screen keyboard. Users will be OK with that, I promise :)

Comment: Thanks for looking into this issue seriously .My requirement is to create the same application like conference manager .Is this the only way to solve the problem  or do you know any another way to solve it.send your mail id .so that i can send my project to you.

Comment: Is there any possible way to do that? kindly reply me.

Comment: No, there's not really much I can tell you. There are no other ways to solve this that I know of, aside from implementing your own dialer app with all the low-level phone stuff. But seriously, it's ok to restrict users in this regard.